# Capacitance value after actuator load

Tags: capacitor, filter, capacitance

[image]I need a little help with the capacitor (in green) in the image above. The problem seems similar to filtering the output of a rectifier but instead of the voltage oscillating back and forth between 0 and V+ it is oscillating between ~11.8v and 13v. Is a capacitor necessary given the IMUs voltage min/max?

$$
C = 0.05/(0.05 x 20 x 1) = 0.05F
$$

The actuator's on/off period will vary but just as baseline the above assumes a 20Hz period, although it will infrequently drop to 0 or slightly exceed 20Hz. Does that capacitance value seem about right?

Thank you!

Comment: 50,000 uF seems high and generally speaking, you want to place the extra filtering capacitance as close as possible to the component causing the fluctuations.  Are you seeing problems with your IMU due to the voltage change?  If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Also, rather than trying to smooth out the 12V bus, you could use a linear regulator with a high PSRR to power your IMU.

Comment: @vir I haven't tried the IMU with the actuators yet. it may turn out that i dont need the cap. regulator was my backup plan if the cap didnt work. thanks for the help.